# ajax call ignoring my if statement

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a modal on my page that submits some data via ajax to my Laravel application, which is then validated to make sure a field is present.

If the field isn't present then Laravel will return a json response with an error status.

I am then checking for the status in the success part of my ajax call for this and displaying an error message if this is the case.

However, even though I am returning an error status, it seems my if statement is missing this and continuing on with the statement.

Below is the whole script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#addShiftButton").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "calendar/addhours",
                data: {
                    'name':$('#name').val(),
                    'start_time':$('input[name=start_time]').val(),
                    'finish_time':$('input[name=finish_time]').val(),
                    'add_shift_date':$('#add_shift_date').val(),
                    'breaks':$('input[name=breaks]').val(),
                    'shift_status':$('#shift_status').val()
                },
                success: function(data){
                    if (data.status == "error")
                    {
                        $("#error").show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#addShiftModal').modal('hide'); //hide popup  
                        //location.reload();
                    }
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have checked the call and it is being successfully made and a json response is received like so: `{"status":"error"}`.

However the `else` part of my `if` statement is being executed. Can anyone see why?

Comment: The response is not **JSON**, it's a _string_. Use `dataType: 'json'` in `$.ajax` configurations or parse it to JSON manually

Comment: true to that, response is always a string, unless specified.

Comment: You need to parse your JSON data before using it. Use JSON.parse(data).

Comment: Use dataType: 'json' in $.ajax or var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#addShiftButton").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "calendar/addhours",
            data: {'name':$('#name').val(), 'start_time':$('input[name=start_time]').val(), 'finish_time':$('input[name=finish_time]').val(), 'add_shift_date':$('#add_shift_date').val(), 'breaks':$('input[name=breaks]').val(), 'shift_status':$('#shift_status').val()},
            success: function(data){
                var result = jQuery.parseJSON( data );  // you need to convert json into javascript array 
                if (result.status == "error")
                {
                    $("#error").show();
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#addShiftModal').modal('hide'); //hide popup  
                    //location.reload();
                }
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

basically what you are doing is trying to access the members of a json object via `data.status` , you have to convert it into a javascript object before doing that as shown in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.parse` to convert `json objects` into `javascript objects`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#addShiftButton").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "calendar/addhours",
            data: {'name':$('#name').val(), 'start_time':$('input[name=start_time]').val(), 'finish_time':$('input[name=finish_time]').val(), 'add_shift_date':$('#add_shift_date').val(), 'breaks':$('input[name=breaks]').val(), 'shift_status':$('#shift_status').val()},
            success: function(data){
            var res = JSON.parse(data);
                if (res.status == "error")
                {
                    $("#error").show();
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#addShiftModal').modal('hide'); //hide popup  
                    //location.reload();
                }
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    });
});
```